# Two Google maps in one application, but with functionalities differ

Tags: android, google-maps, direction

I searched google and unable to find the correct way to achieve this. I have to add two google maps activity to my application. Already merged the manifest. Here is the tricky part, I want one map with direction api enabled, and the other without. Now if I click on the marker, a button shows up in the map where I want the direction api and that's fine. But it is the same with the other one. What is the solution here? Any suggestions will work! Do I need to get another key for thr map?

Comment: Found my answer! Thank you so much anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override onMarkerClick method.
See documentation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker#marker_click_events